# How to correct translation error in WP Astra Taxonomy block

Tags: translation, language

In Astra Child theme, there's a nice Taxonomy block that displays all categories with the number of posts to them. Translated to Dutch, the plural form is wrong. It's "Berichts", should be "Berichten".

In the WordPress Dashboard and in a few other plugins, the translation is correct (and on the whole pretty good).

I read about WPML, but that seems a rather over-the-top solution. It's not a multi-language site.

There would have to be some way of catching the exceptions to the rule 'if plural then add s'.

A quick inspect reveals that the block is called `wp-block-uagb-taxonomy-list`, the offending error is in a div with class `uagb-taxomony-box`, where uagb apparently stands for Ultimate Addon for GutenBerg.

I've spent a few hours googling, to no avail.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Honestly, you should submit this to the Astra development team and they'll add it to their next update (hopefully).   Themes have language files for their translations and when you install WordPress to use a language that isn't english, themes/plugins that have translations will use `.pot` files for that language to change text strings.  If you ever look at WP code for more popular themes you'll notice the text strings are like `_e( 'this is a string of text, 'text domain' )` - then their `dutch.pot` file will have a translation for "this is a string of text" into dutch.